# Getnumber only in lua

Tags: lua

A simple question.
When a roll has been done it shows as:

> ".q,Juf5 KINH GUI NGUOI D'UNG . 8 6 8 6 38 SDU.NG CHO MOT LAN GD NHE;;yGkq,W"

I wish for some way to isolate the number 868638. However there is no such thing as a split in lua (as far as I know) so what's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is the number always the same length? will there be other runs of numbers in the string?

Comment: "However there is no such thing as a split in lua" split is very easy to write. The problem is figuring out what you're actually searching for in that string. I'm not sure what you mean by "when a roll is made" either, you seem to be assuming some context here that we don't have over here.

Comment: 6 numbers near each other

Comment: this's otp verify app but will there be other runs of numbers in the string and otp = 6 numbers near each other

Comment: `n=(s:match'%d%s*%d%s*%d%s*%d%s*%d%s*%d' or ''):gsub('%D', '')`

Comment: thanks @EgorSkriptunoff

Answer (score 1):

```lua
local res = input
   :match(string.rep('%d+%s*', 6))
   :gsub('%D', '')
```